# Getting Out of Memory Exception when downloading large files

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I developed ASP.NET web application. I am trying to download the document from file server. FileSize maybe more than 1GB.

Here the thing is, very first time file got downloaded. when i click the same link, i am getting "Out of memory Exception" throws error.

If it is small size file, i don't get any issues to download the filles...

How do we handle this error if i download the document more than 1GB...?

below is the code to download the file in ASP.NET (Code behind file)

```
         Dim binFile As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(filename)
         Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
         Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename)
         Response.BinaryWrite(binFile)
         Response.End()
```

Answer (score 1):

Response.BinaryWrite() **buffers whole file into memory**, you can Use HttpResponse.TransmitFile() which don't buffer the file in memory.

Better solution is to send file as chunks, stream and ...

**Here is a sample for download file without buffer**

```
using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead("full path to file"))
{
    int bufferSize = 10 * 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    long dataToRead = fileStream.Length;
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=FILE_NAME_THAT_USER_MUST_SEE");
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileStream.Length.ToString());

    while (dataToRead > 0)
        if (Response.IsClientConnected)
        {
            int readLength = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, readLength);
            Response.Flush();
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize - 1 + 1];
            dataToRead -= readLength;
        }
        else
            break;
}

Response.Close();
```